# How can I monitor Facebook hashtag and page like campaign?

Tags: facebook

Our company started a campaign on Facebook where people need to like our page and change their profile picture with our provided image with a hashtag on their profile picture post a few days ago. The three most liked profile pictures will win a price.

Now we are having a big problem on monitoring the campaign, our page has more thank 18k likes and we can't go through each member looking for profile picture. And when searching for our campaign's hashtag on Facebook, it didn't show all post with such hashtag, only a very few post shows up on Facebook search.

Is there a way to monitor our campaign now? Is there a way to use facebook search that will show all post with the specified hashtag?

Answer (score 1):

No there is way to do this as an end user. Probably look into a Facebook Public Content Solutions Partner.